# Custom login backgrounds don't show up

Tags: kubuntu

I want to use a custom login back ground on Kubuntu and I have the settings pointing to the picture I want but it just shows up as black on the login screen.Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you state exactly what settings you used?

Comment: [This answer seems reasonable](http://askubuntu.com/a/112864/22949). I've upvoted it. I suggest keeping this open (it now shows as answered).

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe ?**

Could you show the theme xml file ?
What theme are you using as a template ?

Same kind of problem from the Kubuntu Forums: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?56248-This-SHOULD-be-simple

The default Horos theme is using: wallpaper="Horos".

The documents ( K > Applications > Help > Control Center Modules > Login Screen ) are telling that it should be: file="background.svg". The background could be a pixel file: file="my-wallpaper.png" etc.